# JMS Active MQ communication between two WAR's

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have two war files deployed in the same server (Wildfly) . 
Let's say WAR A and WAR B with thier respective queue configurations in application-context-queue.xml.
Now I have my Message Sender at WAR A and my Message Consumer at WAR B.
Below is my configuration at application-context-queue.xml in WAR A.

```
<!-- File Receiver Queue -->
<bean id="fileReceiverDestination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="someQueue" />
</bean>


<!-- A JMS namespace aware Spring configuration for the message listener container -->
<jms:listener-container
        container-type="default"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        acknowledge="client"
        concurrency="10-50"
        cache="consumer">
    <jms:listener destination="someQueue" ref="simpleMessageListener" method="onMessage" /> 
</jms:listener-container>
```

Now my Bean ConsumerClass refered from simpleMessageListener is present in WAR B. how does the communication takes place between WAR A and WAR B?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You can simply put the required beans in separate configuration files.

Comment: You mentioned activeMQ, the communication happens through the queues. What is not clear here?